# What is the proper behavior for empty string XML attributes in Scala

Tags: xml, scala

I've been working with some XML and I've noticed I'm seeing two different behaviors from scala.xml.Node when it encounters an attribute with a value that is an empty string. As an example, using Scala 2.10.3:

```
scala> val test1 = <Object Name="Test" Attr=""/>
test1: scala.xml.Elem = <Object Name="Test" Attr=""/>

scala> scala.xml.XML.save("test1.xml", test1)

scala> val test2 = scala.xml.XML.loadFile("test1.xml")
test2: scala.xml.Elem = <Object Attr="" Name="Test"/>

scala> test1 == test2
res1: Boolean = true
```

I've got two Nodes (technically they're Elems) that appear to be identical except for attribute order. But when I try to extract the value of the "Attr" attribute, I'm getting different results

```
scala> val attr1 = (test1 \ "@Attr").headOption
attr1: Option[scala.xml.Node] = None

scala> val attr2 = (test2 \ "@Attr").headOption
attr2: Option[scala.xml.Node] = Some()
```

Alternatively:

```
scala> val attrs1 = test1.attributes
attrs1: scala.xml.MetaData =  Name="Test" Attr=""

scala> val attrs2 = test2.attributes
attrs2: scala.xml.MetaData =  Attr="" Name="Test"

scala> attrs1 == attrs2
res5: Boolean = true

scala> val attr1 = attrs1.get("Attr")
attr1: Option[Seq[scala.xml.Node]] = Some(List())

scala> val attr2 = attrs2.get("Attr")
attr2: Option[Seq[scala.xml.Node]] = Some()
```

Any idea where these differences are coming from? What is the correct behavior? Am I basically resigned to using something else to do my parsing if I want to reliably distinguish between an attribute that is just plain missing and an attribute that is present but empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magic happens when you call

```
scala.xml.XML.loadFile("test1.xml")
```

SaxParser empty attribute parsing (test2) results in scala.xml.UnprefixedAttribute with value scala.collection.immutable.List with single element scala.xml.Text with property data: String = ""

Xml created inline (test1) has empty attributes as scala.xml.UnprefixedAttribute with value scala.collection.immutable.Nil

These attributes are equal, because of comparison fun. It compares attributes by org.scala.Metadata#asAttrMap:

```
  def asAttrMap: Map[String, String] =
    iterator map (x => (x.prefixedKey, x.value.text)) toMap
```

As you see, Nil and List(Text("")) has the same value of x.value.text, which equals ""

If you have more questions, I'll be glad to answer